# PIG - Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1s

Tags: count, max, apache-pig

I have data set in the following format:

```
100000853384|RETAIL|OTHER|4.625|280000|360|02/2012|04/2012|31|31|1|23|801|NO|CASH-OUT REFINANCE|SF|1|INVESTOR|CA|945||FRM
100003735682|RETAIL|SUNTRUST MORTGAGE INC.|3.99|466000|360|01/2012|03/2012|80|80|2|30|788|NO|PURCHASE|SF|1|PRINCIPAL|MD|208||FRM
100006367485|CORRESPONDENT|PHH MORTGAGE CORPORATION|4|229000|360|02/2012|04/2012|67|67|2|36|794|NO|NO CASH-OUT REFINANCE|SF|1|PRINCIPAL|CA|959||FRM
```

4th record is the ORIGINAL_INTEREST_RATE.
Now My Question is

What is the interest rate for which most number of people have taken a loan.

I write following codes

**LOAD DATA SET**

```
loanAqiData = LOAD 'hdfs://masterNode:8020/home/hadoop/hadoop_data/LOAN_Acquisition_DATA/Acquisition_2012Q1.txt' 
USING PigStorage('|')
AS 
(
  LOAN_IDENTIFIER:chararray
, CHANNEL:chararray
, SELLER_NAME:chararray
, ORIGINAL_INTEREST_RATE:float
, ORIGINAL_UNPAID_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE :float
, ORIGINAL_LOAN_TERM :float
, ORIGINATION_DATE:chararray
, FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE:chararray
, ORIGINAL_LOAN_TO_VALUE:float
, ORIGINAL_COMBINED_LOAN_TO_VALUE :float
, NUMBER_OF_BORROWERS:float
, DEBT_TO_INCOME_RATIO:float
, CREDIT_SCORE:float
, FIRST_TIME_HOME_BUYER_INDICATOR:chararray
, LOAN_PURPOSE:chararray
, PROPERTY_TYPE:chararray
, NUMBER_OF_UNITS:chararray
, OCCUPANCY_STATUS:chararray
, PROPERTY_STATE:chararray
, ZIP:chararray
, MORTGAGE_INSURANCE_PERCENTAGE:float
, PRODUCT_TYPE:chararray

);
```

**//- Group By Interest Rate**

```
grouped_by_interest_rate = group loanAqiData by ORIGINAL_INTEREST_RATE;
```

**No of Counts for individual Interest Rate**

```
count_for_specific_interest = FOREACH grouped_by_interest_rate GENERATE group as INTEREST_RATE, COUNT(loanAqiData) as NO_OF_PEOPLE;
```

**Dump**

dump count_for_specific_interest

**Output**

(3.625,1)
(3.75,2)
**(3.875,26)**
(3.99,8)
(4.0,21)
(4.1,1)
(4.125,15)
(4.25,16)
(4.375,15)
**(4.376,26)**
(4.5,10)
(4.625,3)

But I want to get 
**(3.875,26)**  and **(4.376,26)**

**How Can I get ?**

**Also If I want to get the Loan Interest for which minimum No of people has taken Loan ..**

Comment: please utilize the code tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the MAX() function (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#max) to determine the highest number of people and then filter by this number.

Here is an example of code that should work (not tested) :

```
FOREACH count_for_specific_interest {
 max_value= MAX($1.NO_OF_PEOPLE);
 GENERATE INTEREST_RATE, NO_OF_PEOPLE, max_value;
}

RESULT = FILTER count_for_specific_interest BY NO_OF_PEOPLE==max_value;
```

For the min you would be able to use exactly the same script replacing MAX() by MIN()

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is resolved.
let me write down the steps

1) Load

2) Group by Interest

```
grp = group loanAqiData by ORIGINAL_INTEREST_RATE;
```

3) Count No of people against each Interest

```
cntForEachGrp = FOREACH grp GENERATE group as 
INTEREST_RATE, COUNT(loanAqiData) as NO_OF_PEOPLE;
```

Output

(3.625,1) (3.75,2) (3.875,26) (3.99,8) (4.0,21) (4.1,1) (4.125,15) (4.25,16) (4.375,15) (4.376,26) (4.5,10) (4.625,3)

4) Group them all to put in the same BAG

```
grpALL = GROUP cntForEachGrp ALL;
```

(all,{(3.625,1),(3.75,2),(3.875,26),(3.99,8),(4.0,21),(4.1,1),(4.125,15),(4.25,16),(4.375,15),(4.376,1),(4.5,10),(4.625,3),(4.75,5),(4.875,4),(5.0,2),(5.25,1)})

5) Calculate Max No of people from the BAG

```
maxVal = FOREACH grpALL {
 max_value= MAX(cntForEachGrp.NO_OF_PEOPLE);
 GENERATE cntForEachGrp.INTEREST_RATE, cntForEachGrp.NO_OF_PEOPLE, max_value as  
 max_no;
}

grunt> describe maxVal;
maxVal: {{(INTEREST_RATE: float)},{(NO_OF_PEOPLE: long)},max_no: long}
```

dump maxVal;

({(3.625),(3.75),(3.875),(3.99),(4.0),(4.1),(4.125),(4.25),(4.375),(4.376),(4.5),(4.625),(4.75),(4.875),(5.0),(5.25)},{(1),(2),(26),(8),(21),(1),(15),(16),(15),(1),(10),(3),(5),(4),(2),(1)},**26**)

6)Filter out Loan interest having Max no of people

```
RESULT=FILTER cntForEachGrp BY NO_OF_PEOPLE == maxVal.max_no ;
```

After dump we get interest Rate -3.875 has max no of people 26.

Why we have to do

```
grpALL = GROUP cntForEachGrp ALL;
```

and

what is the inner meaning of the nested foreach in (5)